# Adopting multiple protocols with Objective-C iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

So, I'm teaching myself iOS development and Objective-C. I completely new to Xcode and Objective-C but not programming.

I might be going about this completely wrong, but I'm trying call a method from a parent view controller from the child view controller.  I tried to use delegation, but I ran into the problem of adopting multiple protocols of different types to the same class. Since I have a table view in my parent view controller, I'm unsure on how to adopt my child view controller delegation.

Essentially, I want to adopt both of these at the same time:

```
@interface MainViewController : NSObject <AddSiteViewControllerDelegate>
```

and

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

I'm new to the language, so this question might have a simple answer.

Comment: You can't inherit from two different classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want both at the same time, it has to be as below

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, AddSiteViewControllerDelegate >
```

UIViewController is a child of NSObject, so by inheriting UIViewController, you would get the behaviors defined in NSObject.

Comment: Thanks, this answer my question, but now my code can't find the delegation protocol. So, I'm marking this one correct because it's the solution to what I asked.

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C supports single inheritance only. That is, a given class can derive from only one other class. However, a class can implement any number of protocols. So a simple solution to your problem would be:

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, AddSiteViewControllerDelegate>
```